# How we count the user draft posts

Tags: count

I am trying to use the total posts count currently i am using the this query

```
$args=array(
'author' => $userID,
'post_type' => 'post',
'post_status' => $poststatus,
'posts_per_page' => 212
);
<?php echo count_user_posts($args); ?>
```

`$poststatus` have 2 options `draft` and `publish`. But when i run this query one condition work good and that is `publish`. but when i try to run `draft` it not showing correct count of draft posts. So tell me where i am wrong in the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `count_user_posts` only accepts a user ID so you arguments are never taken in consideration.
Here is a simple function to get the count by status

```
function count_user_posts_by_status($post_status = 'publish',$user_id = 0){
    global $wpdb;
    $count = $wpdb->get_var(
        $wpdb->prepare( 
        "
        SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM $wpdb->posts 
        WHERE post_status = %s 
        AND post_author = %d",
        $post_status,
        $user_id
        )
    );
    return ($count) ? $count : 0;
}
```

Usage:

```
<?php echo count_user_posts_by_status('draft',$userID); ?>
```